# Xephyr Container with drag and support(XDnD)

Tags: drag-and-drop, x11, xlib

Im relatively new in X11 programming.

I'm looking for some Help related to nested X display Xephyr with drag and support(XDnD). Basically, Here is what Im doing

Xephyr Container with **DISPLAY :1** -> has Java App1 running inside.

Xephyr Container with **DISPLAY :2** -> has Java App2 running inside.

Need to enable Drag and drop support between these 2 Java applications (App1 and App2) running in different Xephyr Containers.

The drag and drop is working fine between 2 java applications, if I run both these java applications in a same Xephyr container(That is with in the same X-display server).

Please let me know is it possible to enable Drag and Support between Xephyr windows(Between 2 nested X-display Xephyr windows) ? If yes any ideas or guide lines will be appreciated.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no support unless someone develops it (not an easy task).

Comment: Thanks for the information n.m